Unable to add drive to raid
I have a 3 RAID arrays on my Linux server.
root@master:~# lsblk -b
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM           SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0           7:0    0    21474836480  0 loop  
loop1           7:1    0    10737418240  0 loop  
sda             8:0    0   512110190592  0 disk  
├─sda1          8:1    0        1048576  0 part  
└─sda2          8:2    0   512107741184  0 part  
  └─md0         9:0    0   511972474880  0 raid1 /
sdb             8:16   0   512110190592  0 disk  
├─sdb1          8:17   0        1048576  0 part  
└─sdb2          8:18   0   512107741184  0 part  
  └─md0         9:0    0   511972474880  0 raid1 /
sdc             8:32   0  3000592982016  0 disk  
└─sdc1          8:33   0  3000591450112  0 part  
  └─md127       9:127  0  9001368551424  0 raid5 
    └─vg0-lv0 252:0    0 11001479036928  0 lvm   /mnt/bigdrive
sdd             8:48   0  4000787029504  0 disk  
├─sdd1          8:49   0  3000591450112  0 part  
│ └─md127       9:127  0  9001368551424  0 raid5 
│   └─vg0-lv0 252:0    0 11001479036928  0 lvm   /mnt/bigdrive
└─sdd2          8:50   0  1000193654784  0 part  
  └─md126       9:126  0  2000116776960  0 raid5 
    └─vg0-lv0 252:0    0 11001479036928  0 lvm   /mnt/bigdrive
sde             8:64   0  4000787030016  0 disk  
├─sde1          8:65   0  3000591450112  0 part  
│ └─md127       9:127  0  9001368551424  0 raid5 
│   └─vg0-lv0 252:0    0 11001479036928  0 lvm   /mnt/bigdrive
└─sde2          8:66   0  1000193654784  0 part  
  └─md126       9:126  0  2000116776960  0 raid5 
    └─vg0-lv0 252:0    0 11001479036928  0 lvm   /mnt/bigdrive
sdf             8:80   0  4000787030016  0 disk  
├─sdf1          8:81   0  3000591450112  0 part  
└─sdf2          8:82   0  1000193654784  0 part  

md0 is a mirror raid and is irrelevant to my problem.
My other 2 raids are RAID 5 arrays.
root@master:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid0] [raid10] 
md126 : active raid5 sdd2[0] sde2[1]
      1953239040 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/2] [UU_]
      bitmap: 0/8 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md127 : active raid5 sdd1[1] sde1[2] sdc1[0]
      8790398976 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/3] [UUU_]
      bitmap: 2/22 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      499973120 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      
unused devices: <none>

root@master:~# mdadm --detail /dev/md126
/dev/md126:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Tue May 21 19:23:02 2024
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 1953239040 (1862.75 GiB 2000.12 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 976619520 (931.38 GiB 1000.06 GB)
      Raid Devices : 3
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Tue Jun 11 19:07:38 2024
             State : clean, degraded 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : master:2  (local to host master)
              UUID : 266af7f7:8915136a:c8630864:2c514c63
            Events : 3201

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       50        0      active sync   /dev/sdd2
       1       8       66        1      active sync   /dev/sde2
       -       0        0        2      removed

root@master:~# mdadm --detail /dev/md127
/dev/md127:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Tue May 21 19:22:19 2024
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 8790398976 (8.19 TiB 9.00 TB)
     Used Dev Size : 2930132992 (2.73 TiB 3.00 TB)
      Raid Devices : 4
     Total Devices : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Tue Jun 11 19:05:40 2024
             State : clean, degraded 
    Active Devices : 3
   Working Devices : 3
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : master:1  (local to host master)
              UUID : cb895040:3fa006aa:88ea4323:15194452
            Events : 25871

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       1       8       49        1      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       2       8       65        2      active sync   /dev/sde1
       -       0        0        3      removed

As seen above, one array has 4 drives and one has 3. Both arrays are degraded with one drive missing each.
I have inserted a new drive "/dev/sdf" that has 2 partitions that exactly matches the sizes of the missing "drives".
The status of the 2 arrays looks identical to me.
Now, when I try to add the new/replaced drives to the 2 arrays, only one works (!!!).
root@master:~# mdadm --manage /dev/md127 --add /dev/sdf1
mdadm: add new device failed for /dev/sdf1 as 4: Invalid argument
root@master:~# mdadm --manage /dev/md126 --add /dev/sdf2
mdadm: added /dev/sdf2

I am even able to add the "/dev/sdf1" drive to the "/dev/md126" array (even though it's too big), so there is no problem with the drive itself.
I am really at a loss here. No idea why "/dev/127" refuses to accept the drive and throws "Invalid argument" without any further details to why...
UPDATE:
root@master:~# cat /sys/block/md126/md/dev-*/state | xargs
in_sync in_sync
root@master:~# cat /sys/block/md127/md/dev-*/state | xargs
in_sync in_sync in_sync

In dmesg, I see this error. No idea why it thinks it would have a superblock already as I am adding a new drive:
md: sdf1 does not have a valid v1.2 superblock, not importing!
md: md_import_device returned -22


1/2 What do you get for the problematic RAID arrays cat /sys/block/md126/md/dev-*/state | xargs and cat /sys/block/md127/md/dev-*/state | xargs? Please add these to your question

2/2 If you've got missing as one of the parameters you need to replace it in the approprate dev-* subdirectory with remove. For example echo remove >/sys/block/md126/md/dev-YYY/state

Actually, I see this in the logs: md: sdf1 does not have a valid v1.2 superblock, not importing!

But now the drive crashed with lots of I/O errors, so I guess my new drive is simply faulty :(

@ChrisDavies I have updated the question is the data you requested. I am now using yet another new drive and still get the same problem.

Make/model number for the new drive please. Is it SMR by any chance

It's a DELL EMC Western Digital. Not sure how I read the model :) It's a 4k sector drive. The others in my array are 512byte sector drives, if that makes any difference? But as it works with one raid array and not the other, I would assume not. I read something similar here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=837964

Oh ok. They look like they're JBOD so you should be able to read the disk model number using smartctl. My mdadm is mdadm - v4.2 - 2021-12-30 - Debian 4.2-5 which AIUI should have the patch referenced in the bug report link you provided. I can't test but it might be worth checking your version and hopefully ruling that out.

"the drive crashed with lots of I/O errors" - with your new replacement can you write to it outside of any RAID? If that works, what about a RAID1 with only one member (the new drive)? Also just starting to wonder if you've a faulty disk slot (Dell may have some diagnostics for that)

The new drive shows no signs of errors. It rebuilt the md126 array without any issues. I only have issue with the md127 array. There is no slot. I am using a SATA to USB adapter for all 4 drives.

@ChrisDavies Yeah, I did check the version after reading it, but I am on version 4.2 as well. Same Debian as you. smartctl does not work with USB-to-SATA adapters apparently, because I can't get any info from the drive, only from partitions.

Loads of people seem to have problems with USB/SATA adapters. Maybe your one can't do 4K sectors? I don't know

@ChrisDavies Could be, but as it works fine with md126, I don't see why it would not work for md127. I am currently taking a backup of everything and will recreate the array from scratch, but this does not make me confident in Linux RAID...

What - the same USB/SATA adapter and the same new disk work for md126 but not for md127?

@ChrisDavies That is correct. The drive has 2 partitions. One is part of the md126 array and the other md127. As seen in my post, one gets added to the array without any issues, the other doesn't. You see it indicated as "sdf1" and "sdf2".

So md126 is now ok? Good. Can you try removing sdf1 from md127 (I would expect this to fail, safely). Also try mdadm --zero-superblock on sdf1 to ensure it really is blank

md126 was always ok. Please see my original post. I can not remove sdf1 from md127, as it refuses to attach in the first place. I have tried clearing the superblock, but it makes no difference, still same error.
